# Spring transaction not rolledback for RuntimeException

Tags: spring-transactions

Code not getting rolled back for RuntimeException..

[image]

This is another configuration file which imports the DatabaseConfig

[image]

I am trying to use Nested Transactions. I have a service class calling repository class..

[image]

Both annotated with @Transactional,
[image]

In deposit, I am throwing RuntimeException, but seems it is not doing rollback

[image]

Calling transfer/ deposit methods using controller. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Complete code also available at :https://github.com/payalbnsl/SpringMvcDemo

Answer (score 0):

If i don't annotate DatabaseConfig with @Configuration, transaction management seems to be not working..

Solved by adding @Configuration on top of DatabaseConfig class.